# Requirement to schedule a job the same date of every month

Tags: sql, unix, scheduling, ksh, teradata

I have a Teradata script (.sql) provided which has few places of code as 'mmyy', 'yyyymmdd', stamp_dt. The requirement is I want to run this script every month on the day 30th. I need to automate this process in UNIX.
For this, first I need to write few more lines in SQL script to make sure of the date formats. What to do here??

Until now, I've added the below lines at the top of the SQL program.

```
#! /bin/ksh

# MONTH END DATE, IN FORMAT YYYY-MM-DD

END_DT=$1

ECHO END DATE IS $END_DT

TODAY1=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
```

But, at few more places I have `MMYY`. What to do in that case?
And how do I add a month every time? Confused here!!

Part of the code is as follows:

```
create multiset  table udxx.hh000_bank_loan_customer_?mmyy as (
sel acct_num, dept,
case when Total_Amt > 500000
then 'R'
else cus_ind
end as cus_lod
from 
hh000_bank_loan_customer a
left join (sel dept_id, type, number from bank_loan) as b
on a.id = b. dept_id
) with data 
primary index (ACCT_ID);
collect stats on udxx.hh000_bank_loan_customer_?mmyy  index(LOAN_ACCT_ID);
```

How do i need to modify the above block of code where 'mmyy' present in order for me to schedule later in ksh script of unix every month.

Do i need to give Addmonths in sql program??

Answer (score 1):

I do this sort of thing with unix only

```
day_of_month=$(date +%d)

if(( day_of_month == 10 ))
then
code goes here
fi
```

What do you plan to do about February?

**Edit starts here**

Regarding requirment to replace strings in your script, you can do this sort of thing.

```
$start_of_month="outside the scope of my answer"
sed "s/start_of_month/$start_of_month/g" original_script > script_for_this_month
script_for_this_month
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.. But, before perfoming this job in unix, i do need to modify the teradata script according to the date formats.

Comment: I did not quite understand this. Say i need to run July 30th, 2014 and i want to run every month 30th. In my sql query when it say 'snapdate', when i run in teradata, it prompts for entering snap date where i enter '20140730', again it prompts for mmyy, i enter 0730, i should first fix it, before scheduling, correct??

Comment: If you are planning to run this as a scheduled job, you have to get rid of all the prompts.

Comment: Exactly. My question is about how to get rid of these prompts in sql code?

Answer (score -1):

Cron in unix/linux is what your possibly looking for. Let the system worry about scheduling your script.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Agree. But, i am talking about the step before scheduling in unix. I can't copy and paste and schedule in unix if i have sql program which has ?mmyy, ?snap_dt at many places. I do need to change them using a couple of date functions, but i am very poor among them.